# Kendo grid drag and drop not working with less number of records

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have integrated kendo grid in my project with drag and drop functionality. I have issue that when there are no records in one grid then the drop functionality is not working as expected. I have to drop the record to one of the record available to work. I have created a sample for the functionality:
[Kendo grid sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/EgAwi/2)

Also, here is the screen shot for the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are specifying that the `kendoDropTarget` is on the grid `table` attribute (which would be specifically the content of the grid).

```
grid1.table.kendoDropTarget({...
```

Change this to use the grid [`wrapper`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget#fields-wrapper) attribute, which encapsulates the entire grid control.

```
grid1.wrapper.kendoDropTarget({
```

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OtALu/3) to demonstrate the above.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)